# What would be a good opensource software for graphing circles, circular regions, and regions bounded by curves and/or arcs?

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics

Hullo all. I have just started s job with Chegg, and my 1st assignment has me writign solutions for Stewart's Essential Calculus. I am dealing with the chapter on multiple integration, and need a good open-source software that I can easily use to draw regions (domains) that would require multiple integrals: i.e. circular regions, portions of circles, regions bounded by curves and/or arcs, and at some point 3D pictures.

In most of these cases, I am not working with an exact equation or perhaps need to draw the region bounded by r (radius) between 1 and 2, and the angle theta bounded between pi/4 and 3 pi/4. I am not too terribly familiar with programs like Corel Draw, but the documents I have from this company suggest Corel Draw. So I think I am looking for an open-source free program like Corel Draw or something similar. Any additional suggestions would also be appreciated. I know I can do most, if not all of this using TikZ, but the learning curve is a bit steep, and at the moment I an on a time constraint. Thanks.

Comment: Try Inkscape.  It's an open-source Illustrator clone, but more simple.

Comment: OK, I'll try Inkscape and see how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use: **gnuplot** or a more simple graphical plotting program from the software centre, then I would use inkscape to do the filling and detail. I don't think there is an easier way to 'draw maths', vector drawing and mathematics doesn't really go well.

gnuplot has a learning curve, but there are some short and concise tutorials, and you can output the graphs as vectors drawings (eps) etc... or high res. what ever suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For a math centric project, maybe give [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) a look.  (In the $$$ world you would use [Wolfram Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica).)

For an images (raster) centric project, maybe give [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) a look.  (In the $$$ world you would use [Adobe Photoshop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop).)

Or like everyone else is saying for images (vector graphics) centric project, maybe give [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) a look. (In the $$$ world you would use [Adobe Illustrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator).)

Oh, oh, if you want to get fancy and create a 3 dimensional world, maybe give [Povray](http://www.povray.org/) a look.  It is a ray tracing package that renders 3 dimensional images.  Geometric images like solid cylinders and cones are easy and only require a dozen or so lines of code/description. Some people have gone nuts and rendered incredible realistic scenes.